# How to change virtual keys color

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[How to change virtual keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFNWz.png)

I want when entered my app change virtual keys fields color like Youtube app,Chrome
Its that possible ? , how can make?

Comment: No, that's the OS.

Comment: But when ı entered chrome and youtube have different color

Comment: Not an Android expert, sorry